# What is the preferred way to access ASP.NET profile in .NET n-tier application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WPF application which talks to a WCF service hosted in IIS. I am also using ASP.NET authorization and authentication to access the service methods. There is also a relatively thin web based interface to the system as well.

What I want is to make use of the ASP.NET Profiles. For example - load profile from server, make changes and then save back to the server. All that with WCF Service calls.

This is my sample User Profile class which is declared server side. I have also defined the appropriate entries in the web.config so it works properly.

```
public class UserProfile: ProfileBase
{
    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
    {
        return Create(username) as UserProfile;
    }

    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
    {
        return Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName) as UserProfile;
    }

    public int? XMLVersion
    {
        get
        {
           return this["XMLVersion"] as int?;
        }
        set
        {
            this["XMLVersion"] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

However I cannot pass it back to the client because ProfileBase is not serializable. Of course I can declare data transfer class which will transfer data back and forth from the profile but it does not look as a very good solution.

So far I am unable to find information how to implement it. Can someone help me with that or point me to another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WCF profile service does what you are asking for. Have a look at it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514968.aspx).

You can see the list of methods it provides in this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.applicationservices.profileservice.aspx)